# Do p-norms of two discrete probability distributions 'rank' them equivalently?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please, forgive me if this is an elementary question, as well as my the sloppy phrasing and notation.

Suppose we have two discrete probability distributions $p = {\lbrace p_i \rbrace}$ and $q={\lbrace q_i \rbrace}$, $i=1,\dots,n$, where $p_i=P(p=p_i)$ and $q_i=P(q=q_i)$. Let's represent them as vectors $\boldsymbol{p} = [p_i], \boldsymbol{q}= [q_i] \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If we take the two p-norms $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot||_b$, excluding 1-norm and max-norm then if $||\boldsymbol{p}||_a>||\boldsymbol{q}||_a$ is it the case that also $||\boldsymbol{p}||_b>||\boldsymbol{q}||_b$ holds? In other words, will all the p-norms induce the same 'ranking' of $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{q}$?

Would anything change if at least one of the $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot||_b$ were p-quasinorms i.e., $a,b\in(0,1)$ instead?

Comment: The formula $p_i = P(p=p_i)$ seems rather peculiar, do you really restrict to such discrete distribution, or would you want to consider all discrete probability distributions? In any case, this seems much more suitable for MSE.

Comment: Sorry, this formula was my poor attempt to clarify my $p_i$ notation:
I meant that by '$p_i$' I denote the probability that the discrete random variable $p$ assumes the value $p_i$. (i.e. like denoting with $x_i$ the probability $P(X=x_i)$).

I do consider all discrete probability distributions, and restrict them to the case that $p$ and $q$ are both n-valued (not that I believe it matters as we could just add zeros to the one with the smallest alphabet to emulate this).

Comment: Yeah, your notation seems non-standard.  You're using $p$ both for a probability distribution, and a random variable having that distribution?  And surely you can't mean $p_i$ is the probability that a random variable assumes the value $p_i$; do you mean the probability it assumes the value $i$?

Comment: Also, based on your comment to my answer, it sounds like you want $\|p\|_a$ to be the $\ell^a$ norm of $p$, considered as a function on $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $\|p\|_a^a = \sum_i p_i^a$.  My interpretation was that $\|p\|_a$ meant the $L^a$ norm of a discrete random variable with distribution $a$, i.e. $\|p\|_a^a = \sum_i i^a p_i$.  Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: Voted to migrate to Math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither  of the two versions holds...

Here are counterexamples. Let $a=1.5$, $b=2$. Let
\begin{equation*}
 p=[3,1,4]/8\quad q = [2,2,5]/9;
\end{equation*}
Then, we have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
   \|p\|_a &= 0.7329,\quad \|q\|_a = 0.7299\\
   \|p\|_b &= 0.6374,\quad \|q\|_b = 0.6383.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

If we use quasinorms, then we can get similar counterexamples.

However, not all is bad. There is a version of the conjecture that does hold. That is, if $p \prec q$, then for all $p$-norms, you'll have the desired monotonicity. That is, $p \prec q$ means the *majorization* order:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    &\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^k p_i^\downarrow \le \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^k q_i^\downarrow\quad\text{for}\   k=1,\ldots,n-1\\
     &\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n p_i^\downarrow = \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n q_i^\downarrow.
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}
In this case, $\|p\|_a \le \|q\|_a$ for all $a \ge 1$.

Comment: Suvrit, thanks again for your answer. I am now at a point where I want to investigate the special case when $p$ is majorized by $q$. Could you direct me to a proof of the theorem you state above? If so, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Nate, first of all thank you for your time. However, I am afraid I am not persuaded by your example.

We have $||\boldsymbol{q}||_a = (q_{2}^a)^{1/a} = q_2 = 1, \forall a$.

On the other hand, we will have $||\boldsymbol{p}||_1 = (1-x) + x = 1 = ||\boldsymbol{q}||_1, \forall x$. The 1-norm case is trivial, since p and q are probability distributions, hence by definition $||\boldsymbol{p}||_1 = ||\boldsymbol{q}||_1=1$, hence I ignore it in my question.

However if $a>1$ then  $||\boldsymbol{p}||_a < 1 = ||\boldsymbol{q}||_a, \forall x \in (0,1)$ and we do get exactly  $||\boldsymbol{p}||_a = 1 = ||\boldsymbol{q}||_a$ for $x \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, when we actually have $p\equiv q$ if we consider the permutations [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] to correspond to different representations of the same probability distribution (I know I did not mention this in my original question...).

Am I missing something?

Comment: For the reference of future readers, we eventually sorted out that I had different definitions in mind, and so I deleted my answer.